# How to get a single row with the maximum value while keeping the whole row?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to get single row for each id where only the maximum value of the charge column is present.

Example input data:

```
id  name charge 
11  hg   10    
11  mm   20
22  aa   40
22  bb   40
```

Code I have tried:

```
df.agg(max("charge"))
```

I am getting only the maximum value, like this:

```
charge
40
```

However, I want to keep the whole row:

```
id  name charge
11  mm   20
22  aa   40
22  bb   40
```

How to keep the first two columns as well? The name column can have different values for the same id so it's not possible to use `groupBy` on both these columns and aggregate the result.

If two rows have the same id and charge both rows should be kept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is necessary to group the rows after the `id` column and then find the maximum value for the `charge` column in each group. If `groupBy` is used to achieve this the `name` column will disappear, as you noticed. Another way is to use a `window` and partition by `id`.

To make sure that both rows are kept when the `id` and `charge` are the same value but the `name` is different, the best way is to add a new column `maxCharge` and then `filter` the dataframe.

Using the example dataframe from the question:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy($"id")
val df2 = df.withColumn("maxCharge", max("charge").over(w))
  .filter($"maxCharge" === $"charge")
  .drop("charge")
  .withColumnRenamed("maxCharge", "charge")
```

Here, first a new column is added with the max value for each `id`. Then the rows with a `charge` value less than this are removed. Finally, the new column is renamed `charge` to match the required output.

Final result:

```
+---+----+------+
| id|name|charge|
+---+----+------+
| 22|  aa|    40|
| 22|  bb|    40|
| 11|  mm|    20|
+---+----+------+
```

Comment: Awesome it worked.. thanks a lot.

Comment: How can we do this, but only keep one row per max? I.e. if charge is 40 in this case, I don't want both rows of "charge == 40", but only one of them at random.

Comment: @ajl123: You should be able to do this by skipping the last 3 lines of code and use `df.withColumn("maxCharge", max("charge").over(w))`.

Answer (score 0):

First step should be to group by on id and fetch `max(charge)` as new column.
second step should be to join input and grouped data set on `input.id=grouped_data.id` and `input.charge=grouped_data.charge`.

```
input:
id  name charge 
11  hg   10    
11  mm   20
22  aa   40
22  bb   40


grouped_data_on_id:
id  max(charge)
11  20
22  40


joined_data_on_id_and_charge:
id  name charge 
11  hg   10    
22  aa   40
22  bb   40
```